# Adding an Extra 2/4 measure into the middle of a 4/4 chorus

Tags: theory

[image]novice song writer here.

I have composed a song that has 8 measures of 4/4 in the verse, but the chorus has an extra measure of 2/4 as a vocal pause in the middle of the chorus. I.e. 4 measures of 4/4, 1 of 2/4, and finishing the chorus with 4 more measures of 4/4.  The extra two beats support the phrasing of the lyrics and fits the "feel" of the song.

The problem I am having is when I engaged the help of a professionally trained friend to help transcribe the song to sheet music.  He is adamant that the chorus needs shortened to be exactly 8 measures to be "standard" form.

The song can be played without the extra two beats, but it sounds rushed and some of the character of the song is lost (to my ear at least).

So music theory question. Being that I have limited experience in these matters, how important is "standard form"?  Is there anything technically wrong with what I want to do?  Seems forcing something into "standard form" is limiting and a lot of interesting music would be impossible.

Edit: This is a performance piece for a Country Gospel band.  Not a worship or congregational song.

Thoughts?

Comment: I skipped the 2/4 bar entirely, and it didn't sound rushed to me at all. I can definitely see where your friend is coming from - jagged phrase lengths also sound amateurish to me, and if your verse is 8 measures long and your song therefore *almost* fits standard form, there's another black mark against you.

Comment: Its your song.  How do you want it to go?  If you want a extra two beats then have them.  You are not required to adhere to any rules.  Make it sound how you wnat it to.

Comment: Like someone else said, beside the 2/4 measure, the beaming in measures 11 and 14 is confusing at best. Except for very simple cases, if a note crosses a beat it should be split into two tied notes.

Comment: You might want to get a "second opinion" from another professional musician, perhaps someone specializing in arranging. Extra half-bars like this are by no means unusual or against a rule. You're already conforming to a much more pressing "standardization," which is: if you don't count your 2/4 measure, but think of it as an extension, then your chorus is two 8-bar phrases. If I were advising you, and if you wanted a 7-bar or 9-bar phrase I might push that point harder, but there's nothing exotic about this "pause." (See https://www.pitchpodcast.org/the-clearmountain-pause/ )

Comment: I wrote an arrangement where I added a measure for the sole purpose of giving me time to stop singing and pick up my horn.  Do what you gotta do.

Comment: Do your thing. As for "extras", listen to despacito / Justin Beaver -- that song got famous partly because of the extra beats.

Comment: If this is intended to be a hymn with a congregation of limited musical training singing along, I would err on the side of keeping the meter as simple and consistent as possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Diverting from the most obvious form by adding a half-length bar (or any other length of time) somewhere can make your song easier to remember and popular, or it can make it more difficult to remember and unpopular. In this case, I think the 2/4 bar is definitely a plus. Prolonging the wait for a harmonic (or rhythmic) turn or event by "adding time" to the basic form with more bars or special length bars can be used to give attention to an important moment in a song. In your song here, an extra 2/4 bar could work very well in that function.

But IMO, you have slightly misidentified what the basic form is, and where the added time is. This is my idea of what the stereotypical form would be:

[image: stereotypical form behind the song]

And if I add a melody to that, the simplified form would look like this: (again, this is my subjective interpretation)

[image: simplified form with melody]

So the thing that you're making the listener wait for is the G chord at the fourth bar of that form. If that's "correct" i.e. how you see it yourself, to explicate that being the case, I'd do the following changes:

[image: sinner too, fixes]

The extra 6 beats of C major makes a point and gives the song something that makes it different and maybe surprising. The sort of stuff that songwriters like to do. If this was a country song, I'd use an alternating bass, but for the 2/4 bar use a descending bass line | C - C - B - A | G ...

(edit: maybe because people talked about 8 bars something, I initially counted the bars wrong. There's actually one and a half bars of "waiting time" added to the stereotypical form, not just one 2/4 bar.)

Comment: Given the 2 quarter-rest equivalents in the middle, I thought the measure notation was perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I'm pointing at the basic obvious form that's being made less obvious here. The big thing that the listener waits for is the G chord, and that's where I imagine an accent cymbal hit. The G bar is where the drum beat is reset. Do you disagree on what the more stereotypical form behind this would be?

Comment: I tend to agree, this is the right notation

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - I thought the "big thing that the listener waits for" already happened at that point and is the C-chord passage in the start of the measure. (Thanks to phrases starting in the middle of measures, the "big thing that the listener waits for" is already irredeemably skewed.) I successfully *cut out* the rests in that region and thought the resulting chorus was just fine (even cutting out the existing 2/4 measure was passable), so it's hard for me to support your measure edits.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I explicated the whole idea together with my imagined melody notes, does that make more sense? I think this might be about subjective experiences, and melody vs harmony, what forms and features are familiar and which aspect of music feel more important. I guess that's one of the fine lines that songwriters try to balance on?

Answer (score 7):

Standard song forms typically have 8-measure sections. Musicians play so many songs like this, that it is natural feeling and predictable. However, there's nothing magical about it. Plenty of songs are written outside of those standard structures, and are outstanding in their own right. There's nothing wrong with what you've written in that regard.

I agree with you that your song needs that 2/4 bar. Keep it.

Answer (score 6):

It's your song, and you deserve to have it played as you wish. So, despite it having the 'oddity' of an extra couple of beats, it should stay as original.

There are, obviously, many, many songs which fit into the 8 bars pattern, and nothing wrong with that. There are also not so many which have quirky bits, like yours. The first few times singing it may well prove tricky for some - so what? Loads of popular songs have quirky bits, which after a few hearings are accepted as such - and if someone plays them differently, they sound odd then! Pretty Woman, 12 Days of Christmas, Golden Brown, various Beatles' songs come immediately to mind - mention them to your friend.

Your pro. trained friend could easily write it out as is. He's probably trying to pigeon-hole the song into a much-loved form, but it'll benefit from being written as you want better. If - at a later stage, you find everyone tries to sing it without the 2/4 bar, then maybe that's the way to go. Easy to scrub them out.

Answer (score 6):

Your 2/4 bar is absolutely fine, and not even particularly unusual.

There are other notation issues in your song though. Get your friend to look particularly at the note grouping in bars 11 and 14.  And start the 2/4 bar with a quarter rest plus an 8th, not three 8th rests.

I agree with @piiperi Reinstate Monica that the 2/4 could effectively come one bar earlier.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Music doesn't need to be in "standard form", but worship music generally should be easy for the congregation to catch on to, since they're meant to sing along.  Using a "standard form" certainly helps with this.

However, my first encounter with a single 2/4 bar in a 4/4 piece was in a kid's worship song, and no one had problems with it.  Our church still does a 5/4 tune and everyone seems to get it.  Your audience is not a bunch of musicians, but they're not totally clueless either.  If the 2/4 bar makes the piece better, then you can keep it.  You'll get further (towards the goal of making your music easy to catch on to) by repeating rhythmic ideas and melodic lines.

Answer (score 5):

I think that a lot of people are missing the train here. If there's a bit of a dramatic pause in the music before that pickup note, there are two approaches that don't require adding two beats into the score.

One is to put the // notation (“railroad tracks,” as my grade-school orchestra teacher referred to them, but you'll have better luck finding this under the name [caesura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura)) before the pick-up note. This indicates that there's a pause at the conductor's/performer's discretion before continuing on.

Another option would be to place a [fermata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermata) () over an eighth note rest, again indicating a pause of indeterminate length.

You could combine the two (putting a fermata over the caesura) to indicate that this should be a **big** pause before continuing.

Comment: I think this answer misses the train!   I can see exactly what is intended.  Maybe if you follow the suggestion of shifting the 2/4 back a bar, you will too.  Put 'do' on a downbeat, then a big drum fill on 2, 3, 4 leading into the next section...  Geddit?   There's no pause or caesura, quite the opposite!

Comment: Trouble with using a fermata is that there's no actual given length for it. Counting/feeling 1 - 2 - in time then singing the next bit means all stay together.

Comment: @tim that’s why there’s a conductor/leader for ensemble performance. Fermatas and caesuras have been part of ensemble performance for centuries. Even non-conductor-led ensembles manage by watching for a subtle signal from the leader (1st violin, e.g. in a string quartet)

Comment: Fully aware of that, having played with  conductors for decades! However, in this sort of music, he wouldn't be necessary if there was a two beat bar *as opposed to* a fermata.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at it metrically, because then I think you can see *why* you probably added in the extra beats. Then you can re-think what you want.

The chorus sets up a `2+2` pattern with a pick up crossing the bar line...

[image]

...so the long note of the word "too" comes on beat `.

Then this rhythm extends the 2 beat length to a full 4 filling an entire bar...

[image]

Then when the `2+2` rhythmic idea is repeated it' *metrical* position is *shifted*...

[image]

...now the long note for "do" is on *beat 3* rather than beat 1. It's sort of like after the full 4 beat bar the `2+2` idea is "late", it's metrically shifted.

IMO skipping the extra bar of `2/4` doesn't make things sound rushed, it more that the metrical shift means the `2+2` phrase is a little late and so it ending long note is a bit shorter that the earlier metrical position placing over the bar line.

This re-baring which a few have suggested...

[image]

...is a way to get that ending long note back on beat 1. That's fine, but it's *after the fact* of hearing the metrical shift. I'm not sure that will really *feel* like beat 1.

If you did cut the `2/4` bar and did this...

[image]

...it would be a similar treatment of the medium long note of beat 3 with quick pickup on beat 4 that happens here...

[image]

That's a bit of internal unity of rhythmic material that supports cutting the bar of `2/4`.

One other thought. The end that "misses" beat 1 in bar 12 emphasizes the incomplete ending of the half cadence on `G`. Then when the second four bar are played and the `2+2` is repositioned to put the ending on beat 1, in bar  16/17 - depending on whether the `2/4` bar is cut, the strong ending, ending on 1 being stronger than ending on 3, emphasizes the periodic phrase structure.

You certainly don't need to cut the bar in `2/4` for the sake of making it fit into 8 symmetrical bars, but on the other hand cutting that bar doesn't seem to destroy the integrity of the rhythms you are using.